# Keras Error: "Optimization loop failed: Cancelled: Operation was cancelled" When Calling predict_on_batch

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I had some older working code that used keras. I recently dusted it off and tried to use it but with current versions of keras/tensorflow. I am getting a warning/error when calling predict_on_batch:

W tensorflow/core/data/root_dataset.cc:167] Optimization loop failed: Cancelled: Operation was cancelled

I tried to google this and, to my surprise, there doesn't seem to be a good explanation on the web as to what causes this or how to fix it. Here is what I did find:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/48689

https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/optimization-loop-failed-cancelled-operation-was-cancelled/1524

The one answer it lists is to make sure the batch size isn't larger than the whole set. That isn't the case here.

The code is a bit long, so I can't easily show it all. It's a deep reinforcement learning app so the DL code is split up across two main functions which I'll show here:

```html
class DQN(QContract):
    def __init__(self, states, actions, lr, DDQN=False):
        self.history = []
        act_relu = activations.relu
        act_linear = activations.linear
        top_layer = 150
        middle_layer = 120
        # Create Network: Default Parameters from https://towardsdatascience.com/solving-lunar-lander-openaigym-reinforcement-learning-785675066197
        model = Sequential()
        layer = layers.Dense(top_layer, input_dim=states, activation=act_relu)
        model.add(layer)
        layer = layers.Dense(middle_layer, activation=act_relu)
        model.add(layer)
        layer = layers.Dense(actions, activation=act_linear)
        model.add(layer)
        opt = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr)
        model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=opt)
        # Create DDQN-like networks
        self.modelA = model
        #self.modelB = copy.deepcopy(model)
        self.batch_size = 100
        self.current = "A"
        self.count = 0
```

```html
    def Update(self, state, action, reward, new_state, gamma, alpha=None):
        # Preform Replay
        row_count = self.batch_size
        if len(self.history) < row_count: return

        # Column names
        state = 0
        action = 1
        reward = 2
        next_state = 3
        done = 4
        # Get samples in mini-batches
        samples = random.sample(self.history, row_count)
        # Separate into separate arrays
        states_array = [sample[state] for sample in samples]
        actions_array = [sample[action] for sample in samples]
        rewards_array = [sample[reward] for sample in samples]
        next_states_array = [sample[next_state] for sample in samples]
        done_array = [sample[done] for sample in samples]
        # Turn into arrays
        states_array = np.array(states_array)
        actions_array = np.array(actions_array)
        rewards_array = np.array(rewards_array)
        next_states_array = np.array(next_states_array)
        done_array = (1.0 - np.array(done_array))

        # train on states_array
        X = states_array

        # Create y (i.e. labels for supervised learning)
        if self.current == "A":
            model1 = self.modelA
            model2 = self.modelA
        else:
            model1 = self.modelA
            model2 = self.modelA

        predicted_values = self.modelA.predict_on_batch(states_array)
        next_predicted_values = self.modelA.predict_on_batch(next_states_array)
        actual_values = rewards_array + gamma * np.amax(next_predicted_values, axis=1) * done_array

        predicted_values[list(range(row_count)), actions_array] = actual_values
        y = predicted_values

        # Update network
        self.current = "A"
        if self.current == "A":
            print('Do fit'+str(self.count))
            self.count += 1
            self.modelA.fit(X, y, epochs=1, verbose=0)
            self.current = "B"
        else:
            self.modelA.fit(X, y, epochs=1, verbose=0)
            self.current = "A"
```

At one point I was trying to do a DQN and I'm not right now, so ignore the attempt to have two models. It's currently disabled.

It seems like this would be a fairly straightforward issue, but I can't seem to figure it out. I even tried stepping through the code and I found it didn't happen when stepping through the debugger.

Comment: For me, I started to get the same warning just after I made `TF` deterministic by calling `tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism()` so no more multi-threading that is used internally!

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/optimization-loop-failed-cancelled-operation-was-cancelled/1524/29) (mentioned by the OP) by now has several replies that suggest that adding the following lines removes the error message:

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem here is in the model not being trainable, because if the weights of the model cannot be updated the optimization loop fails. I had the same issue and all I had to do was to set

```
model.trainable = True
```

Comment: The model does train though. I ultimately get a good result.